# How can I change the name in the window title in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

Here's the screenshot where I've highlighted what I need to modify:

[image]

I want to add version to the window title name. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to show the [`AppVerName`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appvername)/[`AppName`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appname) in the window title, update `SetupWindowTitle` accordingly in the [`[Messages]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=messagessection).

By default it is:

```
[Messages]
SetupWindowTitle=Setup - %1
```

You want to change it to:

```
[Messages]
SetupWindowTitle=Setup - something else
```